# No route to host when i try connect to cloud sql, but only on CONTAINER-OPTIMIZED OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I create instances in Compute Engine and depending on which system I choose, I get different messages when I try to connect to cloud sql. All settings are the same for both machines and the zone.

On CONTAINER-OPTIMIZED OS, the command "nc -vz XXX 5432" running on host (not in docker) returns:

```
XXX: inverse host lookup failed:
(UNKNOWN) [XXX] 5432 (postgresql): No route to host
```

On debian linux it's ok

```
XXX: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [XXX] 5432 (postgresql) open
```

I tried to change iptables but after allowing everything, it's still the same message.

EDIT

Problem reason:

Private address cloud sql is 172.17.2xx.x, docker generate also private network on os with address 172.17.xxx.x and mask /16, so when i try connect i cant because system use docker network.

What is the best solution without changing the os configuration?

Comment: Are you defining the Cloud SQL internal or external IP address?

Comment: I use private adres.

Comment: Is XXX in your command an IP address or a DNS hostname? You must use an IP address for Cloud SQL in private addressing mode unless you have also configured private zones in Cloud DNS.

Comment: XXX is IP address, and i use private addressing. I use default network without cloud DNS. Network configuration on both instances are same. I created also new instance but alwas when i use CONTAINER-OPTIMIZED OS i receive "No route to host."

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the test from a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new network in cloud and now cloud sql have ip from other unconflicted pool.